# Weird file in php (xampp)

Tags: php, file, xampp

I could not find anything anywhere on the internet explaining what you can see in the screenshot.
This is in my xampp folder (as you can see at the top of the screenshot), there is a file why.tmp which was apparently created in 2013. I got this PC in 2017 and now it's 2020.
You can also see the content of the file. I know this question may sound stupid to many of you but I just want to make sure nothing's wrong with my computer.

[image]

Comment: Anything in the `tmp` folder can be deleted (once Apache and mariaDB have been stopped) So ignore it, stop the server and delete the whole content of that folder, but not the folder itself. That file is delivered by the install to stop people deleting it.

Comment: What makes you think that anything is not okay with your computer? Sounds like the file has been added by XAMPP itself

Comment: I thought when I download something it would show me the time I downloaded it as "Date modified". I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is part of xampp. Nothing to do with the computer.

"Temp" / "tmp" folders can mean 2 things:

- The folder holds temporary files
- The folder itself is temporary

From the folder name itself it's never clear although it's usually the first case. So the development team wanted to let you know what it's for. It's pretty clear from the contents of the file in your screenshot.

Well done xampp devs for the smaller details like this.